What are some good French educational shows for toddlers?
A more colloquial way of phrasing the question is, Is there a French Ms Rachel?
J'ai étudié le français au lycée et à l'université. Je l'ai appris à partir de l'anglais, qui est ma seconde langue, l'espagnol étant ma première. Je le lis et écris assez bien, mais je dois beaucoup réfléchir et chercher les mots que je ne comprends pas, et aussi vérifier mon orthographe à l'aide de correcteurs en ligne. Je comprends le français aussi plutôt bien à l'oral si on parle un peu lentement, mais le parler est pour moi le plus difficile. Parce que je n'ai pas vraiment eu l'opportunité de le parler depuis des années, je voudrais donner à ma fille l'opportunité de l'apprendre d'une façon plus authentique que celle que je pourrais lui offrir.
I would love to introduce my young child to entertaining shows that teach her vocabulary, such as letters, numbers, colors, and cultural references.
I know this question can be broad, so here are some examples of what I'm looking for (but with a French speaker):

https://www.youtube.com/@msrachel --> Ms. Rachel uses techniques recommended by speech therapists and early childhood experts to help children learn important milestones and preschool skills
https://www.youtube.com/@bilinguallittlestars --> Ms. Alejandra focuses on teaching young children Spanish, English and American Sign Language (ASL)

The best channels I've found so far are CocoMelon en Français and BlabberBeasts, but my daughter doesn't seem to enjoy them as much as the videos with a real human speaking. The other YouTube channels I've encountered with French speakers aren't as well produced or interesting (in my humble opinion).
Aside from YouTube, I do have several French/English books I read to her (although right now, she's more interested in turning the pages and looking at the pictures than in me reading the stories), and we listen to the CD from the book Un-deux-trois Premières Comptines Françaises https://www.little-linguist.co.uk/un-deux-trois-first-french-rhymes.html
I appreciate your help!

[le français, la française means the French woman]. You can search on sites from France using site:.fr [You need to check your French spelling. :)]

For example: https://savio.fr/ That savio is sanctioned by the French government.

https://www.scribens.fr/ To correct your text.

@Lambie, thank you for the resources :) Savio.fr seems like a robust tool, and I can't wait to use it as she gets older.

https://www.instagram.com/drtaylorbenyahia/ directed me to https://www.youtube.com/@Mimi_Soleil and my daughter has been enjoying
